# MySQL set root password wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to remove the root password. Somehow.. by reading an old post here, I managed to change my password to something that I don't know.I used this exact command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password ''
```

After entering this and my password, I couldn't log in as root anymore. What is that "" representing ?

Comment: A blank password value.

Comment: So how do I input that ?

Comment: Just hit return?

Comment: I get ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

**Recover MySQL root password**

You can recover a MySQL database server password with the following five easy steps:

Step # 1: Stop the MySQL server process.

Step # 2: Start the MySQL (mysqld) server/daemon process with the --skip-grant-tables option so that it will not prompt for a password.

Step # 3: Connect to the MySQL server as the root user.

Step # 4: Set a new root password.

Step # 5: Exit and restart the MySQL server.

Here are the commands you need to type for each step (log in as the root user):

Step # 1: Stop the MySQL service:

```
service mysql stop
```

Output:

`Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.`

Step # 2: Start the MySQL server w/o password:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

Output:

```
[1] 5988

Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
mysqld_safe[6025]: started
```

Step # 3: Connect to the MySQL server using the MySQL client:

```
mysql -u root
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 56299
Server version: 5.6.34-1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql>
```

Step # 4: Set a new MySQL root user password:

***MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier***

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

***MySQL 5.7.6 and newer***

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD("newpass");
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Step # 5: Stop the MySQL server:

```
service mysql stop
```

Output:

```
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
mysqld_safe[6186]: ended

[1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Or use this command to stop MySQL if the command above fails to stop it (which command works depends on the MySQL version):

```
killall mysqld
```

The output might differ based on the Linux distribution. Don't worry unless it reports an error. Start the MySQL server and test it:

```
service mysql start
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: Thank you for this tutorial. But since I am using MYSQL 8.0, I had to do this: mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --skip-grant-tables but doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a password set at all. Try to login typing nothing in the password field. Just type the user only.